# stderr redirection not working in csh

Tags: command-line, freebsd, io-redirection, csh

I run the following command:

```
pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz 2> output.log
```

The output still displays in the terminal. When I press <kbd>↑</kbd>, I get

```
pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz 2 > output.log
```

**with a space before the `2`**.

I did not originally put this. I try

```
pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz > output.log 2>&1
```

Again, when I press <kbd>↑</kbd>, **spaces have been added**.

Why is this happening to me?

I am running csh on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 2> redirect does not work with csh or tcsh.

Use the `chsh` command to change your shell to /bin/sh or /usr/local/bin/bash in order to use the `2>` style redirect. **Note:** Do not change root's shell to /usr/local/bin/bash

csh and tcsh cannot redirect standard out and error separately, but `>&` will redirect the combined output to a file.

Comment: +1 and ✔. I changed shells using `sh`.

Comment: @Craig He's running `pkg_add` on FreeBSD, so I'm assuming this is for the root user (/bin/csh is the default for root on FreeBSD). In this case you should _not_ change the shell to /usr/local/bin/bash. /bin/sh is acceptable. You could also just switch to another shell after logging in as root.

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman Good catch I updated my answer.

Answer (score 22):

I'm not sure if you are trying to hide STDERR or redirect it to STDOUT.

To redirect STDOUT to a file:

```
pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz > stdout.log
```

To redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a file:

```
pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz > & stdxxx.log
```

To redirect STDOUT to a file and hide STDERR:

```
( pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz > stdout.log ) > & /dev/null
```

To redirect STDOUT to console and hide STDERR:

```
( pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz > /dev/tty ) > & /dev/null
```

To redirect STDOUT to console and STDERR to a file:

```
( pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz > /dev/tty ) > & stderr.log
```

To redirect STDOUT to a file and STDERR to a file:

```
( pkg_add emacs-23.4,2.tbz > stdout.log ) > & stderr.log
```

EDIT:
The reason why this works is that the action in the ()'s happens first; Ergo, if we've redirected STDOUT, then it will no longer be available outside of the ()'s. This leaves us with just STDERR, and then we can redirect that as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I know how to do it in Csh, but using 2 shells:

```
csh -c 'SOME_COMMAND 1>/dev/null' |& tee file.txt
```

Such a way allows to redirect *only* stderr to file.txt, without stdout - namely what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to nikc's answer, to achieve the same behavior of Bourne shells, instead of `/dev/tty`, use a FIFO.

To redirect STDOUT to console and hide STDERR:

```
mkfifo stdout
( pkg install -y emacs > stdout ) >& /dev/null & cat stdout
```

To redirect STDERR to console and hide STDOUT:

```
pkg install -y emacs > /dev/null
```