# How to redirect stderr in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, io-redirection

How to redirect stderr in FreeBSD?

Neither of below worked

```
: ls 2> out.log
ls: 2: No such file or directory

: ls -al 2> error.log
ls: 2: No such file or directory

: (ls -al) 2> error.log
Badly placed ()'s.
```

How accomplish?

Comment: This is really about the shell you are using (presumably `csh`), rather than FreeBSD. See for example [stderr redirection not working in csh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35715/stderr-redirection-not-working-in-csh)

Comment: Once you solve the csh issue, it's also necessary for your test command to generate output on the stderr file descriptor.  I don't think `ls` will do that unless you provide a filename on the command line that doesn't exist, for example `ls -l notexist 2> error.log`.